# Minimum user permissions to run a SQL Service Broker Application

Tags: sql-server-2005, permissions, service-broker

I would like to use `SQL Server 2005` Service `Broker` to create an update application. 
The main reason I'm looking to use Service Broker is that I need to call a web service from a trigger (which I've found is not a best practice or even recommended) in a database to update data on another database.

The idea is to use a Service Broker application that will handle the call to the web service asynchronously.

The issue I'm running into, is trying to identify the permissions I have to give my user to be able to create the queues, messages, contracts and actually run the SSB application.

Is there any information available as of what kind of permissions should I grand a user to be able to run the application plus set the `SSB`?

Answer (score 1):

For the app just to operate, you may just need RECEIVE permission on the queue but to setup the SB like creating services, queues, etc... you may need some DDL permissions.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187377.aspx

To begin a dialog, the current user must have RECEIVE permission on the queue for the service specified in the FROM clause of the command and REFERENCES permission for the contract specified.